# How do I access my files and songs in a Creative Jukebox Zen Xtra from Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, creative

How do I access my files in my Creative Jukebox Zen Xtra MP3 player? In Windows XP it should show as a drive where I could drag & drop files. In Windows 8.1, it doesn't show up in This PC. When I plug it in, I see it in Device Manager.

[image]

When I open the properties, I see for Driver Status

> The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)
>   There are no compatible drivers for this device.
>   To find a driver for this device, click Update Driver.

Update Driver says it can't find a driver. I downloaded and installed ZenCast from the Creative size and restarted. http://support.creative.com/downloads/?h=7

It still won't show up in my list of drives. When I go to Sync Manager > Player, it says No Player Connected.

Answer (score 1):

I had to fill out the form on the bottom, select Windows XP x64, and submit. Even though 'All' was selected, there were still hidden files. Then download and installed 'Creative ZEN and Jukebox Driver 2.01.00', 'Creative MediaSource Player/Organizer 5.10.38', and 'Creative ZEN and NOMAD Jukebox Plugin 5.00.22 for Creative MediaSource 5 Player/Organizer'. I may have needed to set compatibility mode and administrator mode for the driver. Use Properties > Compatibility > Windows XP Service Pack 2, and also select the check box for administrator privileges. Then install the driver. Install the others as well. You may need to reboot.

I wasn't able to get Sync Manager working. It doesn't recognize the player is connected.

After installed, run Media Organizer and click on the Nomad Jukebox. Then you can transfer files within the software. I wasn't able to get the Nomad Explorer in the Windows Explorer working to make it show up as a drive.